# Macosx entitlements in Netbeans Java project

Tags: java, macos, websocket, netbeans, entitlements

I have a Java application that needs to work on both Windows and MacOS which is developed in Netbeans 8.2 using JDK8.

This application needs to open a WebSocket, but I'm getting 'Operation not Permited' exception in MacOS, in Windows it works fine.

I have implemented the WebSocket server using 'org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer' class.

The stack trace looks like this:

```
     Operation not permitted
     java.net.SocketException: Operation not permitted
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
        at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.run(WebSocketServer.java:325)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have been reading about possible solutions, but there are very few. One possible solution, taken from an XCode post, could be to add an entitlement file to the application to get the rights to access the network, but I don't know how to do it in a Java project with Netbeans and I do not find any documentation about it.

Edit 1

I think the problem is that the application is launched from another application using the Process.Run method. If I launch it directly it opens the websocket correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but Unix-based systems require root privileges on sockets with port numbers < 1024

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try enabling the Incoming Connections and the Outgoing Connections  from the app that launches your Java process.
In the XCode project you have to go to your Project Settings > Signing & Capabilities > App Sandbox and enable the Network checks.

Hope that helps.